# Parsing Html tags using c#

Tags: c#, html

I have html code:

```
<p>Answer1</p>
<h2>Category1</h2>
<p>Answer2</p>
<p>Answer3</p>
```

I need to do parsing so that each answer (p) belongs to the category(h2) above.
If nothing is above, then the category will be null.

Look like this :

```
obj1.category = null;  obj1.answer = "Answer1";

obj2.category ="Category1"; obj2.answer = "Answer2";

obj3.category ="Category1"; obj3.answer = "Answer3";
```

I tried to solve this, but it was useless.

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: https://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: Alternatively, use [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp)

Comment: I'm using HtmlAgilityPack. I tried to use htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body"); I wanted to take first h2 tag and write the value of this variable to the temporary variable tmpCategory. When I would have met a new tag h2, I would overwrite the temporary variable. thus, to the end, creating objects and entering them into the list

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find that you will have a better
experience if you take moment to take the [Stack Overflow
tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can also read about asking a [good
question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Answer (score 2):

Use [HTMLAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/). It will parse HTML and allow you do use LINQ to `SELECT` whatever you need from the DOM structure.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to HTMLAgilityPack, I've also written a light weight HTML parse for C#.

There's no big secret to the technique, but it's sort of detailed work. You just go through the text character by character and pull out HTML elements.

My parser is on Github as [HtmlMonkey](https://github.com/SoftCircuits/HtmlMonkey).

**UPDATE:**

I just added support for fairly advanced selectors to easily find nodes within a parsed document.

Comment: Interestingly small compared to my [HtmlKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/HtmlKit) library. Does it handle all HTML5 state changes? I see it uses WebUtilities.HtmlEncode()/Decode(). You might like my [HtmlEntityDecoder](https://github.com/jstedfast/HtmlKit/blob/master/HtmlKit/HtmlEntityDecoder.cs) state machine to decode named/unnamed entities. What's missing from HtmlKit is an HtmlDocument type API, but I didn't need it for [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) so I never implemented that. Thanks for sharing, I'll be bookmarking your project for a closer look at some point.

Comment: Sorry, not really familiar with HTML5 state changes. I just Googled that but initial results seemed to be talking about JaveScript. Speaking of WebUtilities.HtmlEncode(), I noticed your code implements a number of utilities that are already implemented in the CLR. Was there a reason for that?

Comment: Yea, mostly for portability across various .NET platforms including PCL, UWP, Xamarin mobile, etc.

Comment: What I was asking regarding HTML5 state changes, was more: is it fully HTML5 compliant? HTML5 defines a very strict state machine for the HTML5 syntax and is one of the reasons why HtmlKit's tokenizer is so large: https://github.com/jstedfast/HtmlKit/blob/master/HtmlKit/HtmlTokenizer.cs

Comment: More information can be found here: https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/tokenization.html

Comment: I took a general approach and haven't done anything specific for HTML5. I've had a hard time getting people to know about and use my parser. I'd love to see more testing and get feedback on any limitations it might have.

Comment: The W3C has a bunch of test cases, most of them just aren't easy to use if you stop at tokenizing like I did ;-)